# IntelliJ Checkout Git Branches

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I've just discovered that you may checkout branches within IntelliJ, without having to open the terminal. My question is: When we use the option to checkout to a certain branch, does it execute a `git pull` automatically? Or do we have to open the terminal and do it ourselves?

Comment: Automatically no, but you can use button with blue arrow to pull current branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDE doesn't run `git pull` automatically after a branch checkout.
If you checked out local branch, then you'll need to use either "Update action" (blue arrow in top right corner of IDE window) or go to Git | Pull.

Please see for more info:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sync-with-a-remote-repository.html

Also there is a Feature Plugin available for IDE, it can help you to learn how to work with features available in IDE:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tutorials/working-with-feature-trainer/ide-feature-trainer-overview/

Answer (score 0):

In git we can work with multiple branches at a time, if the `git pull` was called automatically for a branch it will mess up other branches, and we are required to sort out the conflicts too while doing a `git pull`. These are the reasons I personally feel `git pull` can't be automated.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: It's just an explanation about the query asked, regarding a certain command can run automatically, or is there any way to do it.